# Is there a good .net library for 3-way comparison of HTML that can be used for merge?

Tags: .net, merge, diff

In order to merge independant HTML changes, I'm looking for recomendations for a 3-way comparison / merge library for HTML.  The common 3-way text merge algorithms perform poorly because they do not understand the tree like structure of HTML and XML.  Of course, such a library must understand the looser syntax of HTML, i.e. tags are not always closed. My platform is .Net.

Answer (score 1):

You could also just go cheep: Run the files through [tidy](http://tidy.sourceforge.net/) and then compare. This will result in similar structures, where new / deleted children will show up with traditional diff tools. It breaks down on removal / addition of surrounding nodes - good luck on solving that one...

Also, the [XML Notepad](http://www.snapfiles.com/get/xmlnotepad.html) (sorry, couldn't find a link that works on microsoft.com) by Microsoft can compare XML files and does this in a tree based fashion.

Answer (score -1):

A simple google search offered up: [Differ](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/differ.aspx).  I've never used it so I can't vouch for the quality of that :-)

Comment: Differ does not seem to diff HTML and XML in a tree fashion - just lines, same old stuff diff does ;)